# ansible playbook: Cannot launch a service as root

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been banging my head on this one for most of the day, I've tried everything I could without success, even with the help of my sysadmin. (note that I am not at all an ansible expert, I've discovered that today)

context: I try to run implement continuous integration of a java service  via gitlab.  a pipeline will, on a push, run tests, package the jar, then run an ancible playbook to stop the existing service, replace the jar, launch the service again.  We have that for the production in google cloud, and it works fine. I'm trying to add an extra step before that, to do the same on localhost.

And I just can't understand why ansible fails to do a "sudo service XXXX stop|start" . All I got is

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Sorry, try again.\n[sudo via ansible, key=nbjplyhtvodoeqooejtlnhxhqubibbjy] password: \nsudo: 1 incorrect password attempt\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}

Here is the the gitlab pipeline stage that I call :

```
indexer-integration:
stage: deploy integration
script:
   - ansible-playbook -i ~/git/ansible/inventory deploy_integration.yml --vault-password-file=/home/gitlab-runner/vault.txt
 when: on_success
```

vault.txt contains the vault encryption password. Here is the deploy_integration.yml

```
---
- name: deploy integration saleindexer
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  user: test-ccc #this is the user that I created as a test
  connection: local
  vars_files:
     - /home/gitlab-runner/secret.txt  #holds the sudo password
  tasks:
    - name: Stop indexer
      service: name=indexer state=stopped
      become: true
      become_user: root
    - name: Clean JAR
      become: true
      become_user: root
      file:
         state: absent
         path: '/PATH/indexer-latest.jar'
    - name: Copy JAR
      become: true
      become_user: root
      copy:
          src: 'target/indexer-latest.jar'
         dest: '/PATH/indexer-latest.jar'
    - name: Start indexer
        service: name=indexer state=started
      become: true
      become_user: root
```

the user 'test-ccc' is another user that I created ( part of the group root and in the sudoer file) to make sure it was not an issue related to the gitlab-runner user ( and because apparently no one here can remembers the sudo password of that user xD )

I've try a lot od thing, including

```
shell: echo 'password' | sudo -S service indexer stop
```

that works in command line. But if executed by ansible, all I got is a prompt message asking me to enter the sudo password

Thanks

edit per comment request : The secret.txt has :

```
 ansible_become_pass: password
```

When using that user in command line (su user / sudo service start ....) and prompted for that password, it works fine. The problem I believe is that either ansible always prompts for password, or the password is not properly passed to the task.
The sshd_config has a line 'PermitRootLogin yes'

Comment: This question lacks the crucial file with the password definition; instead it contains a dump of whole playbook. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).　・　The error is clear: provided password was wrong.　・　Also no mention of how `sudoers` is configured.

Comment: provided password is good. When I run from command line, it works fine : su test-ccc / sudo service indexer start / promped to enter the password. Used the same it works. The secret.txt has : ansible_become_pass: password

Comment: In your /etc/ssh/sshd_config, is PermitRootLogin set to yes?

Comment: I'll check that as soon as I can. Why do I need ssh ? I'm on the localhost

Comment: ok so I added a NOPASSWORd in the sudoers for that user, sudo_flags=-u -S in the ansible.cfg et now I have the following error : fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "privilege output closed while waiting for password prompt:\n\nWe trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System\nAdministrator. It usually boils down to these three things:\n\n    #1) Respect the privacy of others.\n    #2) Think before you type.\n    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.\n\nsudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified\n"}

Comment: solution may be with pipe as described here
https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line/67766

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, thanks to a reponse(now deleted) from techraf, I noticed that the line

```
user: test-ccc
```

is actually useless, everything was still run by the 'gitlab-runner' user. So I :

- put all my action in a script postbuild.sh
- add gitlab-runners to the sudoers and gave the nopassword for that script

  gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/PATH/postbuild.sh
- removed everrything about passing the password and the secret from the ansible task, and used instead :

  shell: sudo -S /home/PATH/postbuild.sh

So that works, the script is executed, service is stop/start. I'll mark this as answered, even though using service: name=indexer state=started and giving  NOPASSWD:ALL for the user still caused an error (the one in my comment on the question ) . If anyone can shed light on that in the comment ....